# Do I need a blueprint.xml when using Springs OSGI Dynamic Modules?

Tags: java, spring, blueprint-osgi

I have a spring-context.xml and a blueprint.xml. In the blueprint.xml I am creating a bean that is getting wired into a class in a different project.

Well, I started using Springs dynamic modules for OSGI to load in a configuration file from the OSGI container (which is working) but now I noticed I'm getting an Error creating the bean that is defined in the blueprint.xml

Do I not need the blueprint anymore if I'm defining OSGI properting in my spring context file?

In the blueprint, I have this

How would I use the OSGI Dynamic modules to mimic that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use spring dm or blueprint not both at the same time. I recommend to use rather blueprint than spring dm as the later has a lot of issues with classloading and is not maintained anymore.

Is there any special reason why you move from blueprint to spring dm and not the other way around?

Comment: I was trying to load in a configuration file in my OSGI container as a property file so I used Spring DM because I the properties were used throughout the Spring Xml Configuration so it seemed easier to do. I made a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216189/do-i-need-a-blueprint-xml-when-using-springs-osgi-dynamic-modules/17218734?noredirect=1#17218734 -- if there is a way to load in the .cfg file from the blueprint.xml and be able to use the properties in the spring.xml that would be great...

Comment: The best practice in OSGi to read a property file is using the config admin service. Blueprint as well as Spring DM support this. So make sure you use only one of them. See the spring dm reference docs: http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/compendium.html and for blueprint: http://de.slideshare.net/gnodet/osgi-blueprint-services-1622424

Comment: Can I use the properties loaded in the blueprint in the spring configuration as well?

Comment: No. The contexts are not conntected in any way. But you can configure property placeholders attached to config admin in spring dm. Do you really need both in the same bundle?